# Flutter asynchronous http get requests taking so long to fetch

Tags: flutter, http, asynchronous

My REST API built in NodeJs is hosted on Heroku. In my flutter app, to show a widget I need data from 7 routes which are interrelated. I am using http get to fetch data. The problem is, http get request is asynchronous and I need to fetch from multiple routes results 10-20 seconds to fetch. Here is my code snippet:

```
void initState() {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((value) async {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      try {
        await Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).fetchAllUser();
        await Provider.of<DoctorProfileProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .fetchAllDoctor();
        await Provider.of<CreatedAppointmentProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .fetchAllCreatedAppointment();
        await Provider.of<InstitutionProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .fetchAllInstitution();
        await Provider.of<ReviewProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .fetchAllReview();
        await Provider.of<ChamberProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .fetchAllChamber();
        await Provider.of<AvailableChamberProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .fetchAllAvailableChamber();
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

How can I minimize the fetching time?

Comment: You could try to do your requests in parallel. So instead of `await`ing each of the promises one after the other you could to `await Promise.all([Provider.of<UserProvider>(...).fetchAllUses(), Provider.of<DoctorProfileProvider>(...).fetchAllDoctor(), ...])`

Comment: @derpirscher Can you tell me what the dart equivalent of Javascript ```Promise.all()``` is.

Comment: Oh! I have got it. It is ```Future.wait([])```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try requesting multiple API at the same time as below and update UI once result received:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  final urlList = ['http://google.com', 'http://apple.com'];

  final responses = await Future.wait(
    urlList.map((String url) {
      return http.get(url);
    }),
  );

  final List<dynamic> caches = responses.map((response) {
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }).toList();
}
```

Comment: Though I didn't try yet, can you tell me what will be the responses?  Can I split the respected list of data for a particular API url?

Comment: you will be getting in sequence only here List<dynamic>.